# Text input validation function Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, function, input, onclick

Can someone please tell me why my code isn't working?
I get the error: Cannot read property 'value' of null.

This is my html code:

```
<body onLoad="init()">
<input type="text" placeholder="User Name" id="id_inputuser"></input>
<label>Please Enter User Name</label><br>
<input type="text" placeholder="Password"id="id_inputpass"></input>
<label>Please Enter Password</label><br><br>

<button onClick="verify()">Enter</button>
</body>
```

And this is the JS:

```
function init()
{
var user= document.getElementById("id_inputuser").value;
function verify()
{if (user=="david")
{alert("working")}

else{alert("not working")};
}}
```

Any help will be highly appreciated :)
Thanks a lot!

Comment: When is the _JavaScript_ being invoked? Does the `<input>` _Element_ exist at that time?

Comment: Put `var user= document.getElementById("id_inputuser").value;` within your function. Also, inputs are self-closing.

Comment: Thanks @j08691, but now i get the errors: Unexpected token var
login and init is not defined.
I have an onload function caled init, and the verify function is in it.

Comment: You have no code in your question that contains vars `login` or `init`.

Comment: Please update your question with a complete code example instead of posting it in a comment.

Comment: I updated my code. Is it more clear now?

Comment: why have you put `verify()` in `init()`, it won't get called by the `onclick` event

Comment: It has the same errors whem i take it out

Answer (score 1):

if you say this is the complete code then this is working

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<input type="text" placeholder="User Name" id="id_inputuser"></input>
<label>Please Enter User Name</label><br>
<input type="text" placeholder="Password"id="id_inputpass"></input>
<label>Please Enter Password</label><br><br>

<button onClick="verify()">Enter</button>

<script>

function verify()
{
var user= document.getElementById("id_inputuser").value;
if (user=="david")
{alert("working")}

else{alert("not working")};
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure the javascript snippet you posted is defined AFTER the relevant HTML.
2. Move the `var input...` line inside the `verify()` function.

e.g.

```
<input type="text" id="username" />

<script>
function checkUsername () {
  var value = document.getElementByid('username').value;

  alert( value ? 'Valid' : 'Empty' );
}

document.getElementById('username').addEventListener('change', checkUsername);

</script>
```